# How to find the number of Tags a post has?

Tags: categories, tags, list

Is is possible to find how how many tags (and categories) a post has and to display it?

something like this:
when a post has three Tags and two categories, at the end of the post show that number inside brackets, like so:

TAGS (3)     |      CATEGORIES (2)

I would like to have it so, because i would like that the tag/category list is hidden until the user clicks or hovers it.

Right now i am making the Tags into an unordered list like this:

```
the_tags('<ul><li>','</li><li>','</li></ul>');
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

for tags you can use

```
$tags = get_tags();
$categories = get_categories();

$no_of_tags = count($tags);
$no_of_categories = count($categories);
```

refer this if you need more details :
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

Comment: That seems to give the number of total tags, NOT the number of tags for the post, as it was asked for

Answer (score 2):

Use this,

```
$tags = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'post_tag');
        echo 'TAGS ('.count($tags).')';

$category = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'category');
        echo 'Category ('.count($category).')';
```

for reference
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms

Answer (score 0):

> Use this code on your post loop: ya display on single.php

```
<?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $tags = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID);
         echo 'TAGS ('.count($tags).')';
         $categories = get_categories();
         echo 'CATEGORIES ('.count($categories).')';
    endwhile;
?>
```

[image]

Comment: i have just noticed that with that code i was getting always for the categories te total amount of categories in the blog. it was all the same. I ended up using

    $categories = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, "category");

Comment: This code and above code both are right so you can any code use for your total.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a little bit from all of you, this is what i ended up using:

```
$tags = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID);
echo 'TAGS ('.count($tags).')'

$categories = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, "category");
echo 'CATEGORIES ('.count($categories).')'
```

**Thank you** all for your quick help!  =)